# Deploy mixed code Visual Studio application

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, mixed-code

I have a problem running my application on other machines.

I am developing with Visual Studio 2008 in a Win7 x64 machine.
The solution contains several C# projects (the main application is written in C#, all others are library projects) and two c++/CLI libraries. The C++ libraries are Win32 and all C# projects are set to x86 target processor. No third party libraries used. Framework used is v3.5.
The application builds and runs fine on my machine.
I copied the whole "bin\release" folder to a Win7 x86 machine and it ran fine, too.
But when I tried on a XP x86 system, it did not start. No error message, not even showing up shortly in the task manager. The XP system has all updates installed, all available .NET frameworks installed and all Visual Studio Runtimes installed.
I checked with DependencyWalker and the only missing dlls are "IEShim.dll" and "wer.dll" which are only for Vista or higher.
I tried another of my applications that's not using C++ libraries and they work fine. So I guess I am doing something wrong deploying the C++ dlls.
Registering the C++ dlls with "regsvr32" failed with a "DllEntryPoint" not found message. Registering with "regasm" was successful, but had no effect.

What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like I was a bit hasty stating "no third party components".
Actually it was the SQL Server Compact who was missing its runtime.